# Fluid with blocks remesh modifier jittering

Tags: fluid-simulation

When I added Remesh modifier with option blocks to the fluid mesh, bottom part of the mesh start move up and down.

How I can avoid it?

My blender file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_-tV3odolwlRUgxOUhCVm5Yb3c
Jittering start at 14 frame
Fluid gif 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvbFe.jpg

Comment: What do you add Remesh on fluid object for ? Note that any modifiers will be below the fluid mod in the stack, so the result will be as adding Remesh on the ready fluid. It would be good if you get only one file with .blend extension and compress it (without cache). Cache can be rebaked by those who open the file, no need to upload it.

Comment: Mr Zak, I added remesh to make animated fluid with square parts. The problem is that with this modifier  bottom side of the fluid moving up and down

Comment: From your gif and blend it looks like you are following my tutorial, in which case the solution is at around 13 minutes in https://youtu.be/bpYkNTwK9Pg?t=13m27s

Comment: Ray Mairlot, wow, I didn't expect to see your answer here. Yes, I follow your tutorial, but I faced with problem with jittering. I hadn't realized, what I do wrong. But today I find the crux of problem - Boolean modifier must be placed before remesh modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpYkNTwK9Pg&feature=youtu.be&t

The heart of the problem  that boolean modifier must be placed before remesh modifier.
Maybe this problem is stupid, but I hope that this answer is useful nonetheless.